# CreateView form is not "rendering" in a template tag

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

## Setup

I have successfully setup a CreateView class that allows user to create a Journal. You only have to enter the name and press the "Add" button.

**views.py**

```py
...
class CreateToJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = to_journal
    template_name = 'to_journals/to_journal_list.html'
    fields = ('journal_name',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journals')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateToJournal, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateToJournal, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['to_journals'] = to_journal.objects.filter(journal_user=self.request.user)
        return context
...
```

**to_journal_list.html**

```
...
<form class="" id="myForm" action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <button type="submit" id="add-button">Add</button>
</form>
...
```

This creates a new Journal and reloads the page to reflect the changes made.

I am now trying to move the whole Journal creation process to the "home" page, using a template tag. Mostly it works fine and renders all user journals on the home page, but there is a problem with form rendering.

## Problem

**The new template tag does not render the form created by CreateView**. The input field is not displayed here on the page with a template tag.

I couldn't find any specific information (or general, for that matter) regarding the relationship between forms and templatetags.

My setup for the template tag is the following:

```
...

├───pages
│   └───templatetags
│       └───__init__.py
│       └───journal_tags.py

...

├───templates
│   └───template_tags
│       └───journal_list.html
...
```

Where pages is the app for "static" pages.

**journal_tags.py**

```py
from django import template
from to_journals.models import to_journal

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('template_tags/journal_list.html', takes_context=True)
def get_journals(context):
  journals = to_journal.objects.filter(journal_user=context['request'].user)
  return {'journals': journals}
```

**journal_list.html**

```
...
<form class="" id="myForm" action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <button type="submit" id="add-button">Add</button>
</form>
...
```

**home.html**

```
...
  {% load journal_tags %}
  {% get_journals %}
...
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this question. Any help is appreciated.

If more information is needed I will happily provide.

### Edit

I know realize that I have no reference to the view class created `class CreateToJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView)` in my template tag at all. I couldn't find any resource online that would help me figure it out. How can achieve this? I hope my explanations are celar. Thanks in advance.

### Edit 2

Sorry for not being clear. Here is a little more in depth more clear explanation. Thanks.

Currently, my view `class CreateToJournal(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView)` is rendered at http://127.0.0.1:8000/journals/ and looks like this:

[image]

Here you enter the name and press Add. Page reloads and the new journal is added to the list.

I want to achieve the same thing on http://127.0.0.1:8000/. I thought the best way to achieve this is with a templatetag. Below is the image of my current result. I am now able to pull all the journals on the home page, but the only thing that is not showing is the input field for the journal.

[image]

Ultimately, I want to have a few forms shoing on the home page in the future. I thought that templatetags is a good and sustainable way to do that.

### Edit 3

I am now adding the actual view to the **journal_tags.py**

```py
from django import template
from to_journals.models import to_journal
from to_journals.views import CreateToJournal

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('template_tags/journal_list.html', takes_context=True)
def get_journals(context):
  journals = to_journal.objects.filter(journal_user=context['request'].user)
  return {'journals': journals,
          'form': CreateToJournal(), #new
          }
```

The output is not the actual form, rather the type of the object.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what you are doing. Your template tag returns Journals, which you are not using in the template, instead of the form, which you are using. Why?

Comment: You are confused about what a view is: A Django view processes your HTTP request. One request = one view. The view that processes the request for your home page (which renders the home.html template) is the only view that can populate the context for your home.html template (and journal_list.html template). Your `CreateToJournal` view isn't involved at all. You have to make the view rendering your home.html template a `CreateView`.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks for your replies. I have added additional comments and exlanation in the hope that it will be clearer now. If it is not, I will work on it more. Thanks, hopefully it will clear some things up.

Comment: Well not really. As I said, if you want your template tag to render the form then it must actually return the form, not some completely unrelated Journal objects.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I want both. I've made another edit (#3), which hopefully adds usefull information. My apologies for the unclear explanation and constant edits. This is hopefully a last one. Thanks!!!

Comment: But that's a view, not a form.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman how can I access a form created by the CreateView? If I understand that correctly, CreateView create a form Automatically, right? Or do I have to manually write one in forms.py? Thank a ton in advance.

Comment: You would need to create a ModelForm. It's just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks! ModelForm works, if you submit this as an answer I can upvote and accept it as a solution.